# Align paragraph lines to center with increasing length each line

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to align a paragraph of multiple lines in such a way that with each line the length of the line also increase.

sampleFile.html:

```
<div className="copyright-text">
    <p>Jumma chumma de, jumma chumma de de chumma jumme ke din kia 
       chumme ka vada, jumme ko tod dia chumme ka vaad, lo aa gaya 
       re fir jumma chumma de de chumma 
    </p>
</div>
```

[sample style](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJsRN.png)

Comment: What is the case you've tried, also please reformat your code properly

Comment: Just place breaks <br> where you want to break them.

Answer (score 2):

To center the text use Bootstrap's `text-center` class on the paragraph, then add your own `white-space` rule using `pre`:

```css
p {
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div className="copyright-text">
    <p class=" text-center">Jumma chumma de, jumma chumma de de chumma jumme ke din kia 
chumme ka vada, jumme ko tod dia chumme ka vaad, lo aa gaya 
re fir jumma chumma de de chumma 
    </p>
</div>
```